# How to communicate between node.js and PHP?

Tags: php, node.js, socket.io

I have an existing PHP website and I'm looking to add a real time notification system using node.js

I have outlined the structure of my application into the diagram below :

[image]

I'm assuming communication between PHP and Node.js when the notification is generated is the only way I can achieve a realtime notification (unless I recode my entire website in node.js which is not possible)

How do i communicate to node.js from PHP ? (both exist on the same server or atleast the same local LAN)

I have found a few solutions online and on a few SO threads :

- Using redis pubsub : http://xmeng.wordpress.com/2011/11/14/pubsub-in-redis-using-php/
- Using DNode : http://bergie.iki.fi/blog/dnode-make_php_and_node-js_talk_to_each_other/

Are there other better ways of doing this ?

**Also all the notifications are not beamed to all subscribers.**

So, a notification generated by User 1 will only be beamed to User 2, 3 and 4 (because of a few business rules of my web app)
This permission system needs to be maintained. How do I make sure that all the subscribers do not receive all notifications ?

What is the most efficient way to achieve this ?

Comment: I'd say go with Redis. For you permission system you can send more info per Redis than the message itself. So you could also pack in the info who the notification should go to.

Comment: have you looked into google protocol buffers?

Comment: I assume your Node.js app uses some networking, so why not communicate with it over HTTP? (cURL in PHP, listen on dedicated port on Node.js end).

Comment: Dnode worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I know this answer comes up really late but I've run across the same problem a couple of days ago.

Our solution to this would be using a message broker like RabbitMQ in the middle. Basically, PHP as the `producer` creates messages when there is something to be pushed, and Node.js, on the other side as a `consumer` listens to the queues and publishes messages whenever there is something new.

This method has a couple of advantages over a direct communication between PHP and Node.js.

- First of all, it is async. Therefore, the user will perform its action and doesn't have to wait.
- If, for some reason, Node.js fails, since messages will be stored in RabbitMQ, once you restart node it will simply continue from where it stopped.
- You have Php and Node.js loosely coupled.
- It works.